# Can't get Phone Gap in Android to give me the current time

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, cordova

I'm developing an Android App using Phone Gap, and I have problems getting the current time in the javascript file.

I've tried using the standard Date() call and I get nothing.

```
function getCurrentTime(){
//get current time
var currentTime = new Date();
var timestamp = JSON.stringify(currentTime);
console.log('current time: ', timestamp);
}
```

prints  `"current time: "`

The only other reference I found on phonegap documentation was this:

```
var onSuccess = function(position) {
    alert('Latitude: '          + position.coords.latitude          + '\n' +
          'Longitude: '         + position.coords.longitude         + '\n' +
**********'Timestamp: '         + new Date(position.timestamp)      + '\n');
};

//
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
```

I tried using it but it still prints nothing. Any idea?

```
    var success = function(p) {
        bkme.flags.gettingLocation = false;
        bkme.data.geolocation = {
            'lat' : p.coords.latitude,
            'lon' : p.coords.longitude,
            'accuracy' : p.coords.accuracy,
            'valid' : true
        };

        console.log('time:', new Date(p.timestamp));


    };
    var fail = function(error) { };

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, fail);
```

Comment: where are you testing the app?? can you specify the version for which you are testing and any other settings you have done in you application

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use for my app and it works fine

```
var date = new Date();
var hour = date.getHours();
var min = date.getMinutes();
var seconds = date.getSeconds();
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried skipping the `JSON.stringify` call?

Comment: Have you tried another phone? The Android-browsers are heavily fragmented, could be something there...